# How to use custom sys.excepthook in RootController in TurboGears 2.2.2

Tags: python, logging, turbogears

I want in my TB app to log all exceptions to a log file. So, I tried to use custom sys.excepthook as usual. But every exception is still raised and nothing is logged. Here is my code:

```
class RootController(BaseController):
    secc = SecureController()
    error = ErrorController()

    def __init__(self):
        self.installExceptHook()
        super(RootController, self).__init__()

    def installExceptHook(self):
        def exceptHook(type, value, tb):
            logger = logging.getLogger('app')
            logger.critical(''.join(traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb)))
        sys.excepthook = exceptHook
```

When I raise ValueError in index method:

```
@expose('app.templates.index')
def index(self, **kwargs):
    raise ValueError
    return dict(page = 'index')
```

I still get the WebError Traceback page in my browser and nothing is logged.

Do you know what am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook):

> When an exception is raised and uncaught, the interpreter calls
>   sys.excepthook [...] in a Python program this happens just before the
>   program exits.

Now since WebError catches the exception and handles it (your application doesn't even exit from such exceptions), the exception doesn't reach the point where `sys.excepthook` gets called.

---

For a quick and dirty solution, you could try setting `full_stack = False` in your configuration to disable the WebError middleware (https://github.com/TurboGears/tg2/blob/tg2.2.2/tg/configuration/app_config.py#L1036) this would of course imply that you handle failure response codes in your webserver.

If you just want to log the exception but still use the WebError debugging/eMail functionality, you could just set up a custom middleware, wrap it around your application, log the exception and pass it on.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid there will be some TurboGears middleware.

Comment: @nu.frix I always find it helpful to dig through the TG sourcecode when I'm looking for answers! Sometimes they are quite inspiring :D

Comment: I tried it several times, but I wasn't always successful :) When I got 'redirected' to 5th file, I gave up :D